# Creating a 3D Tic Tac Toe UI using CSS 3D Transforms

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-transforms

I am a complete CSS3 noob, and trying to create a 3D Tic Tac Toe UI using HTML and CSS3 3D transforms.

**I want the UI to look like this-**

[image: 3D Tic Tac Toe Expected UI]

I am using HTML table tag to create the blocks, and CSS3 `perspective` property to give them a 3D look.
Here is the part of my HTML code which creates the blocks-

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And **here is the part of my CSS code, which intends to apply the required 3D effect-**

```
table {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5pt 0pt;
    border-spacing: 0pt;
    -webkit-perspective: 200px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    perspective: 200px;
}

td {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    border: 2pt solid #000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
```

But the problem is that I am not getting the desired results. **The UI I get is far from expected.** You can see the result of my code on JSFiddle here- http://jsfiddle.net/9tLeonhh/embedded/result/

Please tell my how to fix it, and how can I get my expected UI?

Feel free to edit the fiddle.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First you are applying transform on every cell which is wrong.

you should apply transform on table.
for 3D you should set a perspective of the container.
then your object's `transform-style` should be set to 'preserve-3d'.

here is updated fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/singhiskng/kde18fjp/) .

for more take  a look at [using CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms).

Answer (score 1):

You wil need to transform every single `<td>` as you go. I think the easiest way is to wrap is in a div with `position: relative;` and have every cell be `position: absolute;`.

That way you can position and transform all cells with trial and error. I'm sorry I can't think of any other way.

Google Chrome has its feature "inspect element". This actively updates the page when you change CSS. Just right click on your page and it should be on the bottom of the menu.

Edit: Explanation why the original method will not work

When you use perspective on the table and rotate on the cell. The cells will rotate independently, not the table as a whole.